# show rows with where function codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to output only the mysqli rows where the afmeldtijd = 00:00:00
Somehow i got stuck.
I can't find what i am doing wrong.

Controller page

```
public function ajax_list()
        {   
        $list = $this->person->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $person) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $person->datum;
        $row[] = $person->firma;
        $row[] = $person->naam;
        $row[] = $person->telefoonnummer;
        $row[] = $person->werkzaamheden;
        $row[] = $person->opdrachtgever;
        $row[] = $person->pasnummer;
        $row[] = $person->aangemeld;
        $row[] = $person->aanmeldtijd;
    }
```

Models page

```
public function get_datatabels()
{
$this->_get_datatables_query();
$where = "afmeldtijd='00:00:00'";
$this->db->where($where);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public function get_datatabels()
{
 $this->db->where('afmeldtijd','00:00:00');
 $data = $this->db->get('tableName');
 return $data->result();
}
```

change the `tableName` with your table name